# iOS UI Automation Testing in Travis CI

Tags: ios, instruments, travis-ci, ios-ui-automation

I have one small project which I want to test with travis (just to have that green batch on Github) which is https://github.com/SocialbitGmbH/SwiftAddressBook .

It requires access to `ABAddressbook` which can only be given by dismissing an alert when asking for access. So I´m trying to run an UI Automation script to achieve this, which succeeds locally but fails on the remote server with the message

`Instruments Usage Error : Specified target process is invalid: Example/DerivedData/SwiftAddressBookExample/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftAddressBookExample.app`

I repeat, the current configuration *succeeds* locally!

As you can see, I´ve tried countless variations on my .yml file to figure out how it could work (often I´ve rewritten git history, which is why there are many unreachable commits with some other variations). I´d appreciate any help or suggestions (which I have not tried already)

EDIT:

It seems to work more reliable when the simulator had been launched at least once. But even then, there is some non-deterministic possibility of failure

EDIT: I´ve found another way to achieve what I want, but that issue would still be interesting to have solved.

Comment: Ok, two things: I found a different way here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28443578/ios-permission-alerts-removing-or-surpressing/28473742#28473742 , and the launch of the automation script seems to fail because the simulator was never started yet (at least this seems to be one case where it fails)

Comment: Are you using `UIATarget.onAlert` in your UIAutomation code?

Comment: Yes, I did use that, as well as the "direct way" of clicking the button.